# Move rows from one spreadsheet to another spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to copy the last populated row from one spreadsheet to the first not populated row on another spreadsheet. This function works where the source and target sheet are from the same spreadsheet, but not if they are from different spreadsheets.

```
function moveRows() {

  // identifying source & target spreadsheets
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1PugO3VL8ZkGzA6zcYfUkQK4WkU-FfRUBHUzRDTmEbYE');
  let target = SpreadsheetApp.openById('17my-WAAVkZK8m541dH50japQZYQY4WEC_vm12-fCKR8');
  let source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  let target_sheet = target.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  // identifying the ranges
  let row = source_sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  let activeRow = source_sheet.getRange( row ,1, 1 ,10);
  let last_row = target_sheet.getLastRow();

  // row below gives -> Exception: Target range and source range must be on the same spreadsheet.
  activeRow.copyTo(target_sheet.getRange('A'+(last_row+1)+':Q'+(last_row+1)));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to copy formatting, you can just set the values from the source to the next open row of the target.

Give this a try:

```
function moveRows() {
  let sourceSs = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1PugO3VL8ZkGzA6zcYfUkQK4WkU-FfRUBHUzRDTmEbYE');
  let targetSs = SpreadsheetApp.openById('17my-WAAVkZK8m541dH50japQZYQY4WEC_vm12-fCKR8');
  let sourceSheet = sourceSs.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  let targetSheet = targetSs.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  let sourceLastRow = sourceSheet.getLastRow();
  let sourceValues = sourceSheet.getRange(sourceLastRow + ':' + sourceLastRow).getValues();
  let targetNextRow = targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  targetSheet.getRange(targetNextRow + ':' + targetNextRow).setValues(sourceValues);
}
```

Comment: This works great! Can you tell what was causing the error "Exception: Target range and source range must be on the same spreadsheet." in the OP script?

Comment: @ranemirusG I think the issue is that copyTo cannot be used when copying from one spreadsheet to another. The source & destination must be on one spreadsheet for copyTo to work.

Comment: Yup, the copyTo() function only works within the same spreadsheet. I'm not entirely sure why Google decided to make this function only work within the same sheet, but maybe it has to do with how copyTo() also copies the formatting.

Comment: @great_pan Can you also please specify how this would work if I always want to copy the 2nd row from source to target.

Comment: @bigGASsnewbiew If you always want to copy the 2nd row, you can change the following line to specifically pull the range associated with that row:
let sourceValues = sourceSheet.getRange('2:2').getValues();

I should also mention, the script I shared will only work if the source and target sheets both have the same number of columns (since it copies the entire row).

Comment: @great_pan actually never mind. That was as very simple fix actually. 

just added +1 to " let sourceLastRow = sourceSheet.getLastRow() ;"

Answer (score 0):

Move Last Row of Source to next row of target:

```
function moveLastRow() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1PugO3VL8ZkGzA6zcYfUkQK4WkU-FfRUBHUzRDTmEbYE');
  let tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('17my-WAAVkZK8m541dH50japQZYQY4WEC_vm12-fCKR8');
  let ssh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  const svs = ssh.getDataRange().getValues();
  let o = svs[svs.length -1];
  let tsh = tss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const tvs = tsh.getDataRange().getValues() 
  tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, o.length).setValues([o]);
}
```